# Old version of library is included in image after updating bitbake file

Tags: yocto, bitbake

After updating dotnet-runtime in our Yocto based Linux distribution to version 2.1.12, I saw that the resulting image had increased significantly in size. On closer inspection i found that the image contained both the new 2.1.12 version and the older 2.1.11 version of the dotnet-runtime library. How can I ensure that older version are not included in the image? Do I have to change more that just the SRC_URI and checksum?

Here is the content of dotnet-runtime.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = ".NET Core Runtime, SDK & CLI tools"
HOMEPAGE = "https://www.microsoft.com/net/core"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=42b611e7375c06a28601953626ab16cb"
COMPATIBLE_HOST ?= "x86_64.*-linux"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "glibc zlib libunwind icu libcurl openssl krb5 libgssglue"
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "already-stripped staticdev file-rdeps libdir"

INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT  = "1"

SRC_URI =  "https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/c1b620fe-7d8e-4685-b6ae-82b444dbc7a7/3d5610f0607da49ee014c61c6cd4e9af/aspne
tcore-runtime-2.1.12-linux-x64.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "cdb8816a437de168b25500b14ea32169abe610675ced08ca31f77f9542c2149a"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${bindir}
        install -d ${D}${datadir}/dotnet
        install -d ${D}${datadir}/dotnet/host/
        install -d ${D}${datadir}/dotnet/shared/

        install -m 0755 ${S}/dotnet ${D}${datadir}/dotnet
        install -m 0644 ${S}/LICENSE.txt ${D}${datadir}/dotnet
        install -m 0644 ${S}/ThirdPartyNotices.txt ${D}${datadir}/dotnet

        cp -r --no-preserve=ownership ${S}/host/ ${D}${datadir}/dotnet/
        cp -r --no-preserve=ownership ${S}/shared/ ${D}${datadir}/dotnet/

        # Symlinks
        cd ${D}${bindir}
        ln -s ../../${datadir}/dotnet/dotnet dotnet || true
    }

FILES_${PN} = "\
        ${bindir}/dotnet \
        ${datadir}/dotnet/ \
"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the version number to the bitbake file, `dotnet-runtime_2.1.12.bb` instead of `dotnet-runtime.bb`, solved the issue.

Info about recipe naming http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/OEManual/recipes_versioning.html

Answer (score 0):

You might need to clean the cache of the recipe.
Just run:

$ bitbake -c clean {recipe name}

Then build your image again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately cleaning the cache did not solve the issue, but adding the library version number to the filename did.